# Save byte array as .class

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM to transform a java class. Instead of loading the byte array into memory, I would like to save the resulting byte array to a .class file. The ASM manual says this is possible, but does not give an example. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add the relevant quote from the ASM manual.

Comment: just dumping the bytes into an appropriately-named file won't do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open a `FileOutputStream`, `write` the byte array into it and `close` it.